# Momentary on screen button Kivy on Python

Tags: python, kivy

I have the following code which is to make an on screen momentary button to hold a motor on to roll out an awning.

I borrowed the code from an example on github hoping to modify it to my needs.

As you can see the code sets a button to act as a momentary button as opposed to a latching button, which is what I want, however, in this case, no matter how long I hold the button on, the output is only on as long as the Clock.schedule amount which is 1/10 second.

I have tried multiple different ways to get this to keep the output on as long as I hold on the button but I am unable to find a satisfactory solution?

I can make a momentary external (physical) button on a GPIO pin to do this without issue but cannot get it to work on a software button on the screen?

So in a nutshell, what I want to happen is:
While I am pushing the button on my touch screen the motor should keep operating until I take my finger off the button.

Is an anyone able to assist me please? Thanks in advance.

```
#Awning
if obj.text == '[size=24]Awning\n   Out[/size]':
    # turn on output:
    GPIO.output(awnoutPin, GPIO.HIGH)
    # schedule it to turn off:
    Clock.schedule_once(awnout1, .1)   #output stays on if this removed



    #Awning - Momentary
    awningOut = ToggleButton(text="[size=24]Awning\n   Out[/size]",markup = True)
    awningOut.bind(on_press=press_callback)

    awningIn = ToggleButton(text="[size=24]Awning\n     In[/size]",markup = True)
    awningIn.bind(on_press=press_callback)

    layout.add_widget(awningOut)
    layout.add_widget(awningIn)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.5
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.clock import Clock

gui = '''
GridLayout
    cols: 1

    Label
        text: button.name

    MyButton
        id: button
        name: ''
'''


class MyButton(Button):

    def send_signal(self, dt):
        self.name = str(dt)

    def on_press(self):
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.send_signal, 0)

    def on_release(self):
        Clock.unschedule(self.send_signal)


class Test(App):

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(gui)

Test().run()
```

Comment: Thanks jiligeza, I have been away from this project for a while as I was frustrated but I will give it a go this week.